# i tried to fire following soap request in soap ui getting error

Tags: soap, user-interface, exception

i tried to fire following soap request in soap ui

```
<soapenv:Envelopexmlns:soapenv=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”         xmlns:sub=”http://SubscriptionEngine.ibm.com”> 
    <soapenv:Header/> 
   <soapenv:Body> 
   <sub:handleNewSubscription> 
  <custAttributesDTO> 
  <cpId></cpId>  
   <cpPwd></cpPwd>
   <channelName></channelName>
   <productId>111</productId> 
   <cpName></cpName> 
  <aocMsg1>testMSG1</aocMsg1>  
   <aocMsg2>testMSG2</aocMsg2> 
   <firstConfirmationDTTM>2011-10-21T16:02:11.389Z</firstConfirmationDTTM>           <secondConfirmationDTTM>2011-10-21T16:02:11.389Z</secondConfirmationDTTM>  
    <smsContent>SMS Content Test</smsContent> </custAttributesDTO>     </sub:handleNewSubscription> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

i am getting following response pls help

soap:Server.generalException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jdom.xpath.XPath

pls help me in removing this error

Comment: do you have jdom-1.0.jar at the place where the webservice is located